# Barplot/Plot with empty data value

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, week-number

In my data, Week_death represent the week a patient dies. Some weeks none of the patients are dying.

I am trying to do a barplot of mortality of patients. I would like to show the week without death with an empty barplot.

```
death <- table(as.numeric(data$Week_death)) 

barplot(death)
```

The result is the following

[image]

I tried also

```
plot(death)
```

and it gave me this result:

[image]

How do I add empty weeks?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Phil thanks for putting the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `weeks` variable a factor and set its levels. `table()` will retain counts of 0.

```
# Dummy dataset
data <- data.frame(
  week = sample(32:50, 20, replace=TRUE))

# Make week a factor and set levels
data$week <- factor(data$week, levels=c(32:50))

# Get frequencies
# Note that empty factor levels are retained
death <- table(data)
death
#> data
#> 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 
#>  2  2  1  2  1  0  2  0  1  0  1  1  1  2  0  2  1  0  1
barplot(death)
```

[image]